# ln: failed to create symbolic link '/dev/shm/download/file.out': inside docker container

Tags: docker

I have the following docker file. I am trying to create a docker image which runs a python test server.

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

LABEL Author="My Name"
LABEL E-mail="myname@gmail.com"
LABEL version="1.0.0"

ENV FLASK_DEBUG True

RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install -y python-pip python-dev

# We copy just the requirements.txt first to leverage Docker cache
COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt

RUN mkdir /data
RUN mkdir /dev/shm/download
ADD download/file.out /data/
VOLUME /data
RUN ln -sf /data/file.out /dev/shm/download/file.out

WORKDIR /app

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /app

ENTRYPOINT [ "python" ]

CMD [ "test_server/app.py" ]
```

I have a file `file.out` that needs to go inside the docker container. I also want to create a symlink `/dev/shm/download` that will point to that file.

When I run the dockerfile I am getting the following error.

```
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/dev/shm/download/file.out': No such file or directory
The command '/bin/sh -c ln -sf /data/file.out /dev/shm/download/file.out' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

`/dev/shm` is a VOLUME per default. Therefore you can not add data during to that folder as stated in the docker documentation.

> Changing the volume from within the Dockerfile: If any build steps change the data within the volume after it has been declared, those changes will be discarded.

You need to use a different location. Something other than `/dev/shm` for your symlink. If that is not an option you could create the symlink at start time.

---

Source:
* https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#notes-about-specifying-volumes
* https://sondnm.github.io/blog/2018/09/08/i-just-learnt-about-/dev/shm/